# Jackson ObjectMapper NoSuchMethodError problem wiht SpringBoot 2.2.7 and Camel 3.11.2

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, apache-camel, objectmapper

I am trying to setup project with simple post route:

```
        rest("/as2/")
            .post("invoice")
            .description("Receive invoice for sending to AS2")
            .param().name("body").type(RestParamType.body).description("Post message").endParam()
            .route().id("as2-post-route").log("${body}");
```

The application should accept invoices in XML format, convert them and send them to an external system. First I just want to accept the input string and print it.

Error I am getting:

```
org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[]
    at org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException.wrapCamelExecutionException(CamelExecutionException.java:45) ~[camel-api-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at org.apache.camel.support.AbstractExchange.setException(AbstractExchange.java:589) ~[camel-support-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at org.apache.camel.support.DefaultExchange.setException(DefaultExchange.java:27) ~[camel-support-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at org.apache.camel.support.processor.UnmarshalProcessor.process(UnmarshalProcessor.java:81) ~[camel-support-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.process(DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.java:83) ~[camel-base-engine-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at org.apache.camel.support.AsyncProcessorSupport.process(AsyncProcessorSupport.java:41) ~[camel-support-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RestBindingAdvice.unmarshal(RestBindingAdvice.java:307) ~[camel-core-processor-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RestBindingAdvice.before(RestBindingAdvice.java:142) ~[camel-core-processor-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RestBindingAdvice.before(RestBindingAdvice.java:51) ~[camel-core-processor-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:340) ~[camel-base-engine-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.process(DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.java:83) ~[camel-base-engine-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at org.apache.camel.support.AsyncProcessorSupport.process(AsyncProcessorSupport.java:41) ~[camel-support-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.doExecute(CamelServlet.java:319) ~[camel-http-common-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.doService(CamelServlet.java:214) ~[camel-http-common-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.service(CamelServlet.java:130) ~[camel-http-common-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.Object com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(java.io.InputStream, java.lang.Class)'
    at org.apache.camel.component.jackson.AbstractJacksonDataFormat.unmarshal(AbstractJacksonDataFormat.java:185) ~[camel-jackson-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at org.apache.camel.support.processor.UnmarshalProcessor.process(UnmarshalProcessor.java:64) ~[camel-support-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    ... 45 common frames omitted
```

I am using Java 11. Any suggestions? It seams like a libraries clash.

Comment: Probably library problem, please include your gradle / maven setting.

Comment: I upgraded to SpringBoot 2.5.5 and it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Camel 3.11.2 and SpringBoot 2.2.7 are not compatible, needed to upgrade SpringBoot to 2.5.5.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading version for `jackson-core` & `jackson-databind` fixed the issue for me. Upgrade for me was 2.9.10 to 2.13.4.